# How do I display as much text as possible in a fixed-height RDLC cell?

Tags: rdlc, word-wrap

I have a dataset with some possibly quite-wide columns that I'm trying to display in an RDLC report. It's easy enough to set

```
<CanGrow>false</CanGrow>
```

on any given textbox (though since that's the default, removing the CanGrow element does the same thing), but that creates a problem since text-wrapping is still happening, the textbox just isn't growing to accomodate. So (for example)

> ABERCROMBIE & SMITH 
>   SMITH & ABERCROMBIE

will show up in consecutive rows as

> ABERCROMBIE & 
>   SMITH &

Is there a way I can show as much of the text as possible?

Answer (score 0):

### Be Non-Breaking

So here's how I wound up doing it. There are two standard ASCII characters that break, space and hyphen. Space was the easy one; that's just a matter of replacing breaking spaces with non-breaking spaces.

```
<Value>=Replace(Fields!ColumnField.Value, " ", Chr(160))</Value>
```

Hyphens would be possible, since there's a non-breaking hyphen in Unicode (0x2011 = 8209):

```
<Value>=Replace(Fields!ColumnFields.Value, "-", ChrW(8209))</Value>
```

but the non-breaking hyphen character doesn't appear in all fonts. I wound up opening the character map and finding a suitable replacement in my font of choice that wouldn't break or combine - try the modifier letter minus sign (0x2D7):

```
<Value>=Replace(Fields!ColumnFields.Value, "-", ChrW(727))</Value>
```

or the drawn horizontal line (0x2500):

```
<Value>=Replace(Fields!ColumnFields.Value, "-", ChrW(9472))</Value>
```